# Как изменить формат даты для SYSTIMESTAMP

Tags: sql, oracle

Мне необходимо вывести текущую дату, время и часовой пояс в формате: `<ГОД-МЕС-ДЕНЬ ЧАС24:МИН:СЕК.МИЛЛИСЕК ПОЯС>`,
где миллисекунды - это обязательно 3 цифры, а часовой пояс включает минуты (часы:минуты).
Например: `2010-10-02 17:51:32.360 +03:00`
Обязательно использовать `SYSTIMESTAMP`.
Сам `SYSTEMSTAMP` выводит 6 цифр для миллисекунд.

```
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP
FROM DUAL
```

> 2015-11-01 15:39:43.727009 +3:00

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Просто не получилось:

```
 SELECT substr(to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP,'yyyy:mm:hh HH24:MI:SS.FF'),1,23) ||
 to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP, ' TZH:TZM') FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mm:ss.ff3 TZH:TZM')
from dual
```

Comment: А месяц точно не заглавными `M` пишется?

Comment: @Qwertiy В Oracle, в данном случае, формат даты не чувствителен к регистру. Для месяца используется `mm`, а для минут - `mi`. Тут просто ошибка в этом сама по себе.

Comment: @ApInvent, но в ответе `mm` в обоих местах.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, это ошибка. Надеюсь автор просто поспешил и поправит свой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще настроить отображение для всей сессии так:

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3 tzh:tzm';
```

Тогда запрос типа:

```
select systimestamp from dual
```

Будет возвращать то, что нужно:

```
2015-11-02 09:35:12.154 +03:00
```